# How to access SharedPreferences in a ViewModel?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvvm

I am developing an Android application using MVVM. I need to access `SharedPreferences` in a `ViewModel`, but I do not know how to do it.

I know that it is possible to access a context when inheriting `AndroidViewModel`, but I want to know if it is possible and how to do it using DI container (Dagger 2).

Comment: You can also use following approach for ViewModels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673266/viewmodelproviders-with-dagger-2-not-able-to-grasp-the-concept/50681021#50681021

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible. As you mentioned your `ViewModel` has to extend `AndroidViewModel` then call `getApplication()` and use it as context when accessing `SharedPreferences`.

And for using **Dagger 2** in `ViewModel`: you cannot directly inject anything in `ViewModel` either by parameter or field injection, for that you will need to use `ViewModel Factory` and inject objects there first and pass them to whatever `ViewModel` you want.

---

To learn more about using **Dagger 2** with `ViewModels` refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@dpreussler/add-the-new-viewmodel-to-your-mvvm-36bfea86b159).

---

**UPDATE (2020-08-06):**

It is possible to use **Dagger 2** injections in `ViewModels`, check *Kotlin Clean Architecture* library exmaples of how to use it.

https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin

Comment: basically you'll have to inject the view model factory into your fragment/activity and then use it to retrieve the view model. I would recommend this way rather than extending Android view model. Great answer