# Dagger 2 Android - inject() dependencies into ViewModels vs Application with dependency reference(s)

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am creating a basic Android application with Dagger 2. I was having a lot of difficulty understanding how to use it properly until I came across [this great talk by Jake Wharton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plK0zyRLIP8). In it, he demonstrates using Dagger 2 with a "Tweeter" app. At [~22:44](https://youtu.be/plK0zyRLIP8?t=1364), he shows that an app's `@Inject` fields can be satisfied with an inject method. He later shows a simple Android implementation of this.

My app's ViewModels rely on a repository class. I'm using Dagger 2 to inject this repository into the ViewModels, through the Application class, like this:

```
//In my Dagger 2 component
@Singleton
@Component(module = {MyRepositoryModule.class})
public interface MyRepositoryComponent{
    void inject(MyViewModel viewModel);
}

//In MyApplication
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private MyRepositoryComponent repoComponent;

    //Instantiate the component in onCreate...

    public MyRepositoryComponent getMyRepositoryComponent(){
        return repoComponent;
    }
}

//Finally, in my ViewModel
public MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel{
    @Inject
    public MyRepository repo;

    public MyViewModel(@NonNull MyApplication app){
        repo = app.getMyRepositoryComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

I went with this approach because I can override the MyApplication class and use *fake* components for testing (which is one of my main goals here). Previously, the only way I was able to inject dependencies was by building my component *inside* the ViewModels, which makes it impossible to substitute with fakes.

For a simple app like this, I know I could just do away with the inject method and hold a reference to the repository in the MyApplication class. However, **assuming there are more dependencies to worry about, would this be a common/good/testing-friendly approach to injecting dependencies for Activities and ViewModels in Android?**

Comment: Have you considered the approach I outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50681021/2413303 ? It makes the Activity need to know about Application, but ViewModel will no longer need to know about Application (and can use constructor injection).

Comment: I like the idea of using the factory. I may implement this just to have constructor injection and avoid having to make my repository reference package-private or public in my `ViewModel`.
Is there a way to use something like this to provide the `Activity` with a fake `ViewModel` for tests? Or is it more common to keep the `Activity` and `ViewModel` together?

Edit: Mumi's answer mentions multibindings, which I just saw in another article. That may be what I'm looking for in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspiration from [EpicPandaForce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083399/dagger-2-android-inject-dependencies-into-viewmodels-vs-application-with-dep?noredirect=1#comment96925420_55083399) and some research (see [this article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/add-the-new-viewmodel-to-your-mvvm-36bfea86b159)), I've found a solution I'm happy with.

I decided to drop Dagger 2 from my project because I was over-engineering it. My app relies on a repository class and now a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` implementation, which are both needed as soon as the app runs. I learned enough about Dagger for my own satisfaction, so I feel comfortable leaving it out of this particular project and creating the two dependencies in an `Application` class. These classes look like this:

My Application class, which creates my `ViewModel` Factory, gives it it's repository, and exposes a `getViewModelFactory()` method to my Activities:

```
public class JourneyStoreApplication extends Application {

    private final JourneyStoreViewModelFactory journeyStoreViewModelFactory;

    {
        // Instantiate my viewmodel factory with my repo here
        final JourneyRepository journeyRepository = new JourneyRepositoryImpl();
        journeyStoreViewModelFactory = new JourneyStoreViewModelFactory(journeyRepository);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public JourneyStoreViewModelFactory getViewModelFactory(){
        return journeyStoreViewModelFactory;
    }
}
```

My `ViewModel` Factory, which creates new `ViewModel`s with a repository reference. I'll be expanding this as I add more `Activity` classes and `ViewModel`s:

```
public class JourneyStoreViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final JourneyRepository journeyRepository;

    JourneyStoreViewModelFactory(JourneyRepository journeyRepository){
        this.journeyRepository = journeyRepository;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if(modelClass == AddJourneyViewModel.class){
            // Instantiates the ViewModels with their repository reference.
            return (T) new AddJourneyViewModelImpl(journeyRepository);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Requested class %s did not match expected class %s.", modelClass, AddJourneyViewModel.class));
    }
}
```

My `AddJourneyActivity` class, which uses the `AddJourneyViewModel`:

```
public class AddJourneyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = AddJourneyActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private AddJourneyViewModel addJourneyViewModel;
    private EditText departureTextField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_journey);

        JourneyStoreApplication app = (JourneyStoreApplication) getApplication();
        addJourneyViewModel = ViewModelProviders
                // Gets the ViewModelFactory instance and creates the ViewModel.
                .of(this, app.getViewModelFactory())
                .get(AddJourneyViewModel.class);

        departureTextField = findViewById(R.id.addjourney_departure_addr_txt);
    }

    //...
}
```

But this still leaves the question of testing, which was one of my main issues.
Side note: I made all of my `ViewModel` classes abstract (with just methods) and then I implemented them for my real app and the test code. This is because I find it easier than `extend`ing my `ViewModel`s directly, then trying to override their methods and shadow their state to create a fake version.

Anyway, I extended my `JourneyStoreApplication` class (contradicting myself I know, but it's a small class so it's easy to manage) and used that to create a place to provide my fake `ViewModel`s:

```
public class FakeJourneyStoreApplication extends JourneyStoreApplication {

    private final JourneyStoreViewModelFactory fakeJourneyStoreViewModelFactory;

    {   // Create my fake instances here for my tests
        final JourneyRepository fakeJourneyRepository = new FakeJourneyRepositoryImpl();
        fakeJourneyStoreViewModelFactory = new FakeJourneyStoreViewModelFactory(fakeJourneyRepository);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public JourneyStoreViewModelFactory getViewModelFactory(){
        return fakeJourneyStoreViewModelFactory;
    }
}
```

I made fake implementations of my `ViewModel`s and returned instances of them from `FakeJourneyStoreViewModelFactory`. I might simplify this later as there's probably more "fake" boilerplate than there needs to be.

Going off [this guide](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html#how-to-replace-the-application-for-instrumentation-tests) (section 4.9), I extended `AndroidJUnitRunner` to provide my *fake* `Application` to my tests:

```
public class CustomTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override
    public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return super.newApplication(cl, FakeJourneyStoreApplication.class.getName(), context);
    }
}
```

And finally, I added the custom test runner to my `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Espresso
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.<my_package>.journeystore.CustomTestRunner"
    }
}
```

I'm going to leave this question open for another 24 hours in case anyone has useful things to add, then I'll choose this as the answer.